# How can I change a query inside a package to use the last execution datetime of job?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a daily job that runs a SSIS package to select the count of records from a table for the previous day using a date range. I want to change it to run every few minutes so I need to save the datetime used in the previous run query to a variable which I want to store in another DB table. It was suggested I store it using IO but not sure what they meant by that.

```
SELECT [authorUrl],[postDate] ,[dateadded]
FROM [Feeds].[dbo].[XMLFeed]
where CONVERT(DATE, DateAdded) = DATEADD(DAY, -1, CONVERT(DATE, SYSDATETIME()))
order by dateadded desc
```

How can I change the where statement to be where dateadded is equal to or greater than the last time this select was run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must stored the last execution value in a table somewhere. First, create a table to hold your last execution paramters :

```
create table LastExecutionParameters
(
  Id int identity(1,1) not null,
  LastExecutionDate datetime
)
```

Then, use it that way :

```
declare @executionDate datetime = 
    (select top 1 DateAdd(Day, 1, LastExecutionDate) 
       from LastExecutionParameters 
      order by Id desc);

SELECT [authorUrl],[postDate] ,[dateadded]
FROM [Feeds].[dbo].[XMLFeed]
where CONVERT(DATE, DateAdded) = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @executionDate)
order by dateadded desc

insert into LastExecutionParameters values (@executionDate);
```

Of course, change the `dateadd` call to fit your needs.